# Add delay between two messages in Microsoft BOT Framework (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-bot-service

I try to get delay between two messages from bot side.

```
await turn_context.send_activity(f"text1")
sleep(2)
await turn_context.send_activity(f"text2")
```

I tried different options but most works like after my respond to bot first runs sleep command and only after I receive text1 & text2 without delay.

How it could be solved?
Thanks.

Comment: Try with  `await asyncio.sleep(2)` it should work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the below sample code to print the message delay by 4 seconds by using the `await asyncio.sleep(4)` function with python version `3.7.*`

**sample code:**

```py
import  asyncio

async def  main():
print('message1 ...')
await asyncio.sleep(2)
print('... message2!')

# Python 3.7+
asyncio.run(main())
```

***Output screen for the sample code in VS code which delays by 4 seconds to print the message2 after printing the message1:***

[image]